# What is an Inyan? Is it different to a Minhag?

Tags: minhag, words

Is there a difference between an ענין and a מנהג? If so, what is it?

Examples differentiating the concepts would be useful.

Comment: Why would you think they are the same? What do you know about these words already? I'm familiar with a meaning of the second but not the first

Comment: Maybe we should add these to https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/581/ instead of asking their meanings here?

Comment: @DonielF How can we add them to the glossary without knowing what they mean?

Comment: @Alex What I mean is that someone who *does* know what they mean (like [Avrohom Yitzchok](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101777/) apparently) should add them there. (I’m actually kinda surprised that minhag isn’t there already.)

Comment: @DonielF It can't hurt to leave this question to figure out if the meaning might not be so straightforward. Especially if we already have one person who seems confused about it.

Comment: ענין is  as there is a consistent reason to make this. Perhaps this is not a custom at all. Minhag is simply a custom

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91982/is-there-an-inyan-to-pronounce-each-word-clearly-in-davening#comment298960_91982

Comment: I believe most people when they use the term don't know what they're saying.

Comment: Inyan can be translated idea or reason. Minhag means custom. They aren't directly related at all although one could speak of an idea or reason behind a custom.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100874/ptij-what-is-the-inyan-of-the-konami-code-in-uncle-moishys-song

Answer (score -1):

The way I've always heard them used is akin to the difference between a chiyuv, requirement, and a chumra, a stringency.

So a minhag would be more binding, and an inyan is more voluntary.

There is a minhag to do xyz, so make sure to do it, vs there's an inyan to do abc, so it's nice to do.

(As a side point most times that people talk about something being an inyan, it is something they have no comprehension about the action or the reasoning behind it. Their use of inyan makes a minhag logical.)